# Can we configure external Solr server with DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Pls have look at this article [Configure External Solr server with Governance Registry](https://cnapagoda.blogspot.tw/2015/07/configure-external-solr-server-with.html) . Can we configure external Solr server with DAS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to do with WSO2 DAS 3.0.1, as it is using solr 5.2.1. You can exactly follow the steps mentioned in above post to enable it for DAS.